# Authorization help in asp net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having a hard time understanding on how to add some sort of authorization to my application. This is how my login controller looks like now:

```
private UserProvider mUserProvider;
    // GET: Login
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        string userName = AuthenticateUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)))
        {
            Session["UserName"] = userName;
            return View("~/Views/Home/Default.cshtml");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Bad login");
            return View("~/Views/Home/Login.cshtml");
        }
    }

    public string AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
            //do stuff and get the special username
            return sUsername;
    }
```

What would I need to add in order to make sure a non authenticated user can´t view any other page besides the login?

ps: I am 100% required to use AuthenticateUser.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried decorating your other secure action methods with `[Authorize]`?

Comment: `[Authorize]` on the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the [Authorize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute on all of your other controllers, users will not be able to access any methods within those controllers if they are not authenticated.

```
public class LoginController
{
}

[Authorize]
public class HomeController
{
}
```

In this case, all of your `LoginController` methods look like they should allow anonymous access and you should decorate them as such.  Also, making `AuthenticateUser` private would probably be a good security measure.

Comment: I tried adding that and now the "main page" does not show anything is there anything i need to add for the Authorize tag to have an effect?

Comment: @jiggergargle Check the http response.  Is the status code a 401?  If so, that would indicate it IS working and you aren't authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

Decorating the action methods you want to secure with `[Authorize]` would work. You can even add this at the controller level and selectively `[AllowAnonymous]` on specific actions.

It's useful if most of your action methods need to be secured, to register a `GlobalFilter` so that all actions are treated as `[Authorize]` by default. This way you're less likely to miss one and inadvertently allow anonymous access to a route that should be secure.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

If you're using FormsAuthentication, in your web.config you can set a  default redirect for any calls that are made to secure action methods where no valid session exists.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="/login" protection="All" path="/" timeout="60" />
</authentication>
```